# Sympy: rewrite an expression in terms of a constant

Tags: constants, sympy, substitution

I am new to Sympy, sorry if this question has an obvious answer.

I would like to rewrite an expression containing nothing but constants (i.e., no symbols (?)) in terms of a constant defined earlier.

```py
from IPython.display import display
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()

r = sympy.S.GoldenRatio - 1
display(r)
display(1 - r)
display(1 - r**2) # equals r
```

Displays the following expressions:

[image: Result under Jupyter Notebook]

But I would like:

```
r
1 - r
r
```

(Not sure whether I am actually asking two distinct questions here, one for the first two lines of the result, one for the last line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following kind of gets you there. Printing the expressions with `StrPrinter(dict(order='none')).doprint(expr)` didn't work well even for unevaluated expressions because of a parenthesizing issue.

```
>>> sr= Symbol('(GoldenRatio - 1)')
>>> r= S.GoldenRatio - 1
>>> r.subs(r, sr)
(GoldenRatio - 1)
>>> (1-r).subs(r, sr)
1 - (GoldenRatio - 1)
>>> nsimplify(1-r**2).subs(r, sr)
  1   v5
- - + --
  2   2
>>> nsimplify(1-r**2,r.args).subs(r, sr)
(GoldenRatio - 1)
```

or

```
>>> nsimplify(1-r**2,[S.GoldenRatio]).subs(r, sr)
(GoldenRatio - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, as a sympy newbie, I don't see how this code gets me close to the desired output, i.e., express the values in terms of r (not ). What am I missing?

Comment: OK, I got it. Replacing your first line with `sr = Symbol("r")` made the trick. Thanks!

Comment: yes - I didn't know you wanted a literal `r`.